# Среди элементов массива с одинаковым значением свойства оставить лишь один

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив обьектов со свойствами, например:

```
<?php
$products = array();
$products[] = (object) array('id' => '1', 'price' => '100');
$products[] = (object) array('id' => '2', 'price' => '200');
$products[] = (object) array('id' => '3', 'price' => '300');
$products[] = (object) array('id' => '4', 'price' => '200');
$products[] = (object) array('id' => '5', 'price' => '300');
$products[] = (object) array('id' => '6', 'price' => '200');

foreach($products as $product) {
    echo $product->id.': '.$product->price.'<br/>';
}
?>
```

Нужно сделать так чтобы среди элементов у которых price одинаковые т.е. среди 2, 4 и 6 (у них у всех price 200) и среди 3 и 5 (у них price 300) оставить в массиве лишь по одному с "группы", а остальные убрать, или через unset() или как, не знаю. Не имеет значения какой именно оставить просто какой то один "представитель группы". Т.е. на странице должно вывести не

```
1: 100
2: 200
3: 300
4: 200
5: 300
6: 200
```

а например

```
1: 100
2: 200
3: 300
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вообщето просто если не надо какой либо систематизации то можно последний элемент брать в массиве

```
$result = array();
foreach($products as $product) {
    $result[$product->price] = $product;
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Подходит, спасибо!

Comment: @stckvrw спасибо тут говорят отмечая вопрос как верный слева галочка, а так всегда пожалуйста )

Comment: Знаю) Просто галочку тут не сразу дают возможность поставить)